# What does the ambient light sensor look like?

Tags: sensors, htc-one-v

Naive question, but when I check the specs of a phone, one website says phone has feature X, the other says it does not have this feature. Here I am interested in the ambient light sensor.

What does it look like, and where it is usually placed?

**For example**, [GSM Arena review says](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_v-review-750p2.php) the HTC One V has an ambient light sensor: "Above the display is the earpiece alongside some hidden proximity and ambient light sensors." The photo:

[image: HTC One V with hidden ambient light sensor]

For comparison the text says I should see the proximity sensor too. On my Galaxy Ace 2 it looks like 2 mini cameras, it is hard to miss, and on that picture I don't see anything like that. Of course maybe HTC hid that all so well.

Anyway, I would like to know what I am looking for, thus the question -- **What does the ambient light sensor look like?**

Comment: In your picture here, the light sensor is in that small patch to the left of the htc logo.

Comment: Stand up or tilt your monitor down and you will be able to see it in the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to see it in normal light, you may need to take your phone under a very bright light to be able to see it (e.g bulb light or straight sunlight). It looks like a darker and smaller front face camera.

If GSMarena has said that it has light sensors, then in my experience, its near 100% correct.

BTW, if you can't bring light sensor to work, there is a free software called [Lux Auto Brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux) which does the job very nice and has many options.

Comment: Hard to decide which answer mark a solution :-) LUB is not compatible with Ace 2, I believe it requires exactly what I asked for -- ambient light sensor :-) But thank you for the tip.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your phone is HTC One V, however if your phone has front camera, you still can use Lux because it also works with camera! and uses front camera of phone as a light sensor.

Comment: Google Market filters out the apps which won't work on present phone. So when using a computer I can see this app, but when I try to download it the app is not found.

Answer (score 7):

The sensor is like a small dot, usually located on the left of the HTC logo, above your device's screen. Also the location of the proximity sensor is.

<sup>FYI: HTC ONE models S, X, V, EVO 4G LTE are very much alike in physical conception.</sup>

This is covered at XDA Developers forum thread: [Where is the One X's ambient light sensor?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1633148)

> **By Tiersten:**
>
> Left of the HTC logo above the screen. It is also where the proximity sensor is.
>
> **By jaaystott:**
>
> If you call someone, take a look at the front of your phone. You will see a steady red glow from the top left of your screen, this is where the proximity and ambient light sensor are housed.

---

Additionally, there's this White Paper: [Ambient Light Sensor (ALS) Applications
in Portable Electronics](http://www.rohm.com/documents/11303/41217/CNA09016_wp.pdf) that shows their physical aspect:

[image: Ambient Light Sensor physical aspect]

Answer (score 7):

Just so that I can play a little with gimp: Here's the photo with the light sensor marked.

[image: HTC One V with light sensor]

Comment: If you're playing with Gimp you could have added some contrast to make it more visible.